Superscript/exponent (footnote mark) interfeers with setstretch < 1
So, my PhD advisor insists that displayquotes must have small font with a "squashed" interline. So I have been using a \setstretch{x} where x<1. The issue I am having is that when there is a footnote in the displayquote, which happens often, then the line where the footnote mark is located has a larger interline above it. In other words: the footnote mark "pushes" the line above it up a little.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \setstretch{0.8}\small{#1#2#4#3}%
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1][1-2]

  \blockquote{%
    \lipsum[1][2-5]\footnote{Blablabla}\lipsum[1]
  }

  \lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}

My first question is this: doesn't interline spacing change proportionally to font size? If so, then I guess my setstretch is superfluous.
If not, then is there an explanation for my problem? Or a good way to prevent the superscript text from messing with interline spacing?
Perhaps the problem is that I don't understand how line spacing works in LaTeX, so any pointers to good reading about that would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Mark.
Note: this was edited after the discussion in comments. My initial - first ever - question was very poor. Thanks for the help in formulating it better.

you might be able to manage .9 or so but  \setstretch{0.5} makes no sense you are specifying a line spacing that is smaller than the letters on the line so there is no hope of getting even spacing: footnote marks of course but a simple thing like a line with no capital letters will have closer spacing than one with. If your supervisor insists on that then they get what they get.

Welcome! I'm not sure what the problem is. If you set \small inside the quotation, the interline skip is accordingly reduced. With \setstretch{0.5} your lines will all be too near to each other and will be distanced by \lineskip every time.

Ok so... my bad for using an exagerated setstretch. In the initial test I had it at 0.8 and that was looking reasonable, save for lines with a footnote mark. Perhaps I'll edit the MWE to use something closer to my real world case.

Your example does not use a smaller font, if it did, the baseline would be smaller anyway without using \setstretch

0.8 * 1.2 is 0.96 so still smaller than many characters in the font. You can't place 10pt characters on lines 0.96pt apart

Right, all of this is coming from the fact I picked apart the MWE too much. You are correct, if I keep a reasonable setstretch such as 0.9 or 0.95 then there is no interference from the footnote mark

no harm done, please edit the question so that it shows an example that has a chance of a reasonable answer.

Do either of you want to make an answer or shall I just delete this very bad first question?

possibly delete is best:-)

I can propose three solutions. In the first one nothing special is done, except choosing a smaller font.
In the second and third, the interline spacing is reduced by 10%; in the third one, though, also the footnote marker is made smaller.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{displayquoteA}
 {\begin{quote}\small}
 {\end{quote}}

\newenvironment{displayquoteB}
 {\begin{quote}\linespread{0.9}\small}
 {\end{quote}}

\newenvironment{displayquoteC}
 {\begin{quote}\lowerfnmark\linespread{0.9}\small}
 {\end{quote}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lowerfnmark}{%
  \renewcommand\@makefnmark{\raisebox{0.7ex}{\normalfont\tiny\@thefnmark}}%
}

\lineskip=20pt % just for testing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{displayquoteA}
\lipsum[2][1-2]\footnote{text} \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{displayquoteA}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{displayquoteB}
\lipsum[2][1-2]\footnote{text} \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{displayquoteB}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{displayquoteC}
\lipsum[2][1-2]\footnote{text} \lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{displayquoteC}

\end{document}

Take your pick. The \lineskip=20pt line is just to ensure that lines are not considered too near to each other, so \lineskip glue is not inserted. Going less than \linespread{0.9} will not work.

